# pdo driver odbc sqlsrv driver not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, installation, centos

```
$this->_connection = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$serverName,1433; Database=".DB_NAME.";",DB_USER,DB_PASS);
```

This is my connection to database. I have installed `php71-php-odbc.x86_64 0:7.1.9-1.el7.remi` using the command `yum --enablerepo=remi install php71-php-odbc` it confirmed installation by

```
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : php71-runtime-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                                  1/5
  Installing : php71-php-common-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                             2/5
  Installing : php71-php-json-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                               3/5
  Installing : php71-php-pdo-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                                4/5
  Installing : php71-php-odbc-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                               5/5
  Verifying  : php71-php-json-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                               1/5
  Verifying  : php71-php-odbc-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                               2/5
  Verifying  : php71-php-common-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                             3/5
  Verifying  : php71-php-pdo-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                                4/5
  Verifying  : php71-runtime-1.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64                                                                                                                  5/5

Installed:
  php71-php-odbc.x86_64 0:7.1.9-1.el7.remi

Dependency Installed:
  php71-php-common.x86_64 0:7.1.9-1.el7.remi  
  php71-php-json.x86_64 0:7.1.9-1.el7.remi  
  php71-php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.1.9-1.el7.remi  
  php71-runtime.x86_64 0:1.0-1.el7.remi
```

In the command line. The thing im confused is the output of `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` is

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlite
)
```

I am expecting that odbc will be added in the result. Also if i run `php -m` in the command there is no odbc in module list in command.

What is the correct way to install the driver need for the connection stated above.

`Server runs centOS 7`

`Update`

> Installing odbc driver to get rid of error saying **Caught exception: could not find driver**

Answer (score 0):

1/ you have installed php71 which is a SCL (parallel installation), so ensure you use the right php command

```
# /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/php -r 'print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());'
Array
(
    [0] => dblib
    [1] => firebird
    [2] => mysql
    [3] => oci
    [4] => odbc
    [5] => pgsql
    [6] => sqlite
    [7] => sqlsrv
)
```

2/ Perhaps you need a single PHP version, check the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

3/ More information red  [Microsoft SQL Server from PHP](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/09/20/Microsoft-SQL-Server-from-PHP)

Comment: mate `/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/php -r` after running it i get `bash: /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/bin/php: No such file or directory` does this mean something is wrong in my installation and that is the reason why i cant connect using `odbc`?

Comment: found your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027457/php-with-mssql-not-installing-in-centos-7) i wanted to try it but i get error saying `Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-Om8xoE/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm: epel-release-7-10.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-Om8xoE/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
` ***How to fix  this?***

Comment: Looks like you have install additional extensions as SCL (php71-php-*), when you need base package (php-*), see the Wizard: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/